# USB 3.0 PCIe Card not working

Tags: drivers, usb

I bought a this [USB PCIe Card](https://www.delock.de/produkt/89297/pdf.html?sprache=en) and while it works perfectly fine in W10, it is not recognized in Ubuntu 20.04. Truth be told, I don't remember if Ubuntu were able to recognize it at first and then failed, or if they had issues from the beginning.

My contact with Delock has not solved any problems, since they just blamed the "dual boot" of my system, while not trying to understand what I was telling them.

Datasheet states that the card is compatible with Linux ex Kernel 3.4 and I guess with any more recent version.

Any ideas on what should I do?

Obviously I don't want to mess with Ubuntu or kernel version!
BIOS USB settings are all turned on and legacy off (MOBO: ASUS TUF B450-PLUS)

Edits:

- Card works perfectly fine with my other Ubuntu 20.04 computer (MOBO: Asus Sabertooth 990 FX)
- Bios is able to recognize usb flash drives that are connected to PCIe Card
- Ubuntu Live version on the problematic computer is not able either to detect the card

So... it seems like a problem specific to my computer...

The fact that it is not recognized not in live version, either on the proper installation, but yet, it is recognized on another machine running ubuntu, make me think that this is a BIOS thing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Except for GPUs, PCI-e expansion cards rarely require additional drivers or configuration - especially cards that add ports (USB, Ethernet, SATA, etc).  Are you sure that the device is correctly installed?  It looks like it needs to be connected to SATA power.

Comment: @Nmath I am sure that the device is correctly installed since it works perfectly fine in Windows 10. Actually, when a usb flash drive is connected to the PCIe Card, it is recognized even from BIOS. The problem seems to affect only Ubuntu, for reasons unknown... actually I will edit my post with some new info tomorrow.